# PHP passing variable id through href

Tags: php

I want to have a link to another page, with particular subject, How can I pass the id ?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Add Topic</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach($subjects as $sub):?>
            <td><?php echo $sub->subject;?></td>
            <td><a href='approve.php?id=".$sub->id."' role="button" class="btn">Add Topic</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you need to look at $_GET and $_POST.  I'd advise against using hyperlinks and GET method requests for things that change the state of the server though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to echo it out.

```
<?php foreach($subjects as $sub): ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $sub->subject ?></td>
    <td><a href="approve.php?id=<?php echo $sub->id ?>" role="button" class="btn">Add Topic</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: any idea how to hide id in url

Comment: use base64_encode, crypt or any other encoding function in php

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

```
<table class="table table-hover">

    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Add Topic</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($subjects as $sub):?>
    <tr>


        <td><?php echo $sub->subject;?></td>
        <td><a href='approve.php?id=<?php echo $sub->id; ?>' role="button" class="btn">Add Topic</a></td>

    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and then on the page : approve.php

```
<?php
$subjectId  = $_GET['id'];
?>
```

`$subjectId` will give you the corresponding subject id with which you can move forward with the functionality.

Note: **foreach** should start either outside `<tr>` and end outside `</tr>` or it can be inside `<tr> </tr>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your variable in a PHP tag:

```
<?php foreach($subjects as $sub):?>
  <tr>
     <td><?php echo $sub->subject;?></td>
     <td><a href='approve.php?id=<?php echo $sub->id ?>' role="button" class="btn">Add Topic</a></td>

   </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

There is also a short form echo tag enabled on most PHP servers `<?= $variable ?>`

On the subsequent page you retrieve the parameter from the **GET** array:

```
$subject = $_GET['id'];
```

If you're passing this value to the database you should do some validation:

```
if ($_GET['id']) { // check parameter was passed
  $subject = int_val($_GET['id']) // cast whatever was passed to integer
} else {
  // handle no subject case
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, it will be considered as GET. as for how to pass it. 
Edit the following:

```
 <td><a href='approve.php?id=<?=$sub->id?> ' role="button" class="btn">Add Topic</a></td>
```

This is the part:

```
 <?=$sub->id?>
```

You closed php tag when u started adding html therefore open it again to echo php vars.

Comment: I hit enter by mistake :(

Comment: by hitting enter the form does not submit!

Comment: @GordonM well, now my full answer is there.

Comment: Why i'm still being -1 ?

Comment: <?php =$sub->id?> is not going to echo the value of $sub->id

Comment: @SaurabhSinha So I better stop misguiding innocent people. * *sigh* *
I've edited my answer.