# Linking one php script to another

Tags: php

What i'm trying to achieve is to link my already completed SQL table query to another SQL table query. So to give some more information we need to make a game for my school assignment. I'm making a little Pokemon battle game. I've queried my SQL table and it's giving me all the Pokemon_Type that it currently has in the table. I want users to be able to click on that table entry that's being displayed and then it queries the database again displaying information on that type. [Here is the webpage in question.](http://nuttyhosting.tech:1234/PokemonFight.php) Don't judge my html skills xD. So as you can see atm there is the 'Electric' type so i'd like to be able to click on that and it refreshes the page and shows all the Pokemon that's associated with that type in the SQL table. Is this possible? and if so how?

Here is my code so far if you'd like to see it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%
        }
        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px
        }
    </style>
    <title>Pokemon Fight!</title>
    <center>Pokemon Fight!</center>
</head>
<body>
Select your type!

<?php
require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');

$query = "SELECT pokemon_type FROM pokemon";

$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

if($response){

echo '<table align="left"
cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">

<tr><td align="left"><b>Pokemon Type</b></td></tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){

echo '<tr><td align="left">' . 
$row['pokemon_type'] . '</td><td align="left"></td>';

echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

} else {

echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";

echo mysqli_error($dbc);

}

mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use a `join` and pull the additional information in one call, then hide it in the DOM until needed. Alternatively you could make an AJAX call when the pokemon is selected. Dont use the `@` you should resolve whatever errors are being reported. Separately `<center>Pokemon Fight!</center>` shouldnt be in the `head`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest is to create a link into you pokemon type label to another page passing your type id through href.
Look at this post, it's about what you want to do : [PHP passing variable id through href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967931/php-passing-variable-id-through-href)

But using ajax would be better to load informations dynamically without reloading the page