# How do i set up a remove button to delete a row from a table that is on MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL . I'm using PHP to display table contents and I added a button that will remove a row once it's clicked. I'm can't get the button to use delete.php to remove a row from the table and from the database. Any suggestions ?

Thank you

*shopping-bag.php*

```php
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>MODEL</th>
        <th>QUANTITY</th>
        <th>COLOR</th>
        <th>PRICE</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect(
        "localhost",
        "user",
        "pass",
        "db"
    );
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT productname, productmodel, productquantity,
                    productcolor, productprice FROM posts";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["productname"] . "</td><td>" .
                $row["productmodel"] . "</td><td>"
                . $row["productquantity"] . "</td><td>" .
                $row["productcolor"] . "</td><td>"
                . "$" . $row["productprice"] . "</td><td>" . "<input type='button' name='removerow' action='delete.php' value='REMOVE'>" . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

*delete.php*

```php
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "user";
$dbpassword = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

//Connect
$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

//DELETE query
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE ID = '$_GET[id]'";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        header("refresh:1; url=shopping-bag.php");
    } else {
        echo "NOT DELETED";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Note that it's unusual to 'hard delete' data in  this way

Comment: In simple ways, you can change the button to anchor tag and in href, give delete.php?id=1 You can make the id field dynamic sending values from DB via PHP . Learn more at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967931/php-passing-variable-id-through-href

Answer (score -1):

In shopping-bag.php, you need to retrieve ID in your loop over the `SELECT` statement results, and put it as an argument to `action='delete.php?id=$id'`.

Also recommend reading [cross-site scripting](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/OWASP_Top_Ten_2017/Top_10-2017_A7-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS)) and [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/OWASP_Top_Ten_2017/Top_10-2017_A1-Injection) so you can avoid these common vulnerabilities in your code.

Comment: Are you sure this would work? According to me, it will not work.

Comment: Can you correct me on specifics? or include own answer.

Comment: If you write `action='delete.php?id=$id'` it will not work. Try it with a simple HTML. You should use click event or use `<a>` tag.